# $|z-w| \leq |w| $ implies $|z+w| \geq |w| $?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

If $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers such that
$$|z-w|  \leq |w| $$ is it true that
$|z+w| \geq |w| $ ?

I believe this is true but I don't know how to prove it. Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $|z-w|\leq|w|$ so that $-|z-w|\ge-|w|$. Then,
\begin{multline*}
\left|z+w\right|
=\left|2w+z-w\right|
=\left|2w-\left(w-z\right)\right|
\geq2\left|w\right|-\left|w-z\right|
\\=2\left|w\right|-\left|z-w\right|
\geq2\left|w\right|-\left|w\right|
=\left|w\right|
\end{multline*}

Answer (score 1):

Recall the parallelogram identity:
$$|z - w|^2 + |z + w|^2 = 2|z|^2 + 2|w|^2.$$
Hence,
$$|z - w|^2 + |z + w|^2 \ge 2|w|^2.$$
Therefore, at least one of $|z - w|^2$ or $|z + w|^2$ must be greater than or equal to $|w|^2$, which is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

$|z+w|\geq 2|w|-|z-w|\geq |w|$.

Answer (score 0):

$$|z + w| \ge |2w| - |w - z| \ge 2|w| -  |w| = |w|.$$